# sails return error when create new user to postgresql without id

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, orm, sails.js

I want to create a new user into a PostgreSQL database using sails. in my PostgreSQL database, I have a sequence for my id field. and in my model.js I have :

```
attributes: {
id: {
  type: 'number',
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  autoIncrement: true,
},
first_name: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},
last_name: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},
company: {
  type: 'string',
  allowNull: true
},
url: {
  type: 'string',
  allowNull: true
},
email: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true,
  isEmail: true
},
password: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},}
```

my object to create is :

```
    { first_name: 'g',
  last_name: 'f',
  company: 'f',
  url: 'u',
  email: 't@h.co',
  password: 'Aa123456@' }
```

but when i try to run my project i got an error `Missing value for required attribute`id`.  Expected a number, but instead, got: undefined`. what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `id` is required field, the validation during the ORM lifecycle is failing as it expects `id` to be present.

Either you can remove the `id` attribute from model and the Postgres will automatically take care of the auto increment field or you will have to add a `beforeValidate` hook/function where you explicitly assign the data to `id` field before validation.

Sample of `beforeValidate` hook: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/639#issuecomment-55845733

Comment: and how sails use it? I don't know how it works! I used your function but I couldn't see anything even in console